# Is there a way to filter a Salesforce report by a list of values?

Tags: filter, reporting, salesforce, apex-code

Ok, so I want to have a report that does not require the end user to know all about writing and customizing reports or memorizing field values. I ultimately want the user to be able to use a collection of prepopulated SelectList based filters on an apex page I've created to filter their report.

So far I have this as far as being able to filter by *one* value for each field:

1. Create an Account report
2. Add a filter for BillingState Equals *blank* (This is filter #1, or index 0)
3. Create a Page with a SelectList and use a Controller to populate it with a list of States
4. Create a CommandButton on the page and use a PageReference object to redirect to the Report
5. At the end of the URL for the report, add pv0 (parameter value for index 0) = [selected state]

So this is all well and good - instead of having the user memorize valid field values and mess with report filters they can point and click stuff - so simple a sales person could do it.

But now I want to filter by a **list** of states (or some other text field). I can easily get a String[] list of states with the multiselect attribute of the SelectList, but I don't know how to go about applying it to the report. In an SQL sense I want add a "State=x OR State=y OR State=Z" or "State IN (x, y, z)" where condition to the reports query.

---

How could I go about doing this - filtering a report by a list of valid values for a field, and doing it programmably from a controller?

- Is there some method to programmably create a temporary report on the fly? Clone a "template" report and then add OR filters as needed?
- Is there a way to pass a set of objects to a report? Some reports return a lot of results, so this seems dangerous.
- When doing PageReference redirection the Redirect attribute states that when it is false all the state information is retained, but the destination page must have the same controller - is there a way to use controllers with reports to customize their logic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I get you right, you're almost there.

Add your criteria values comma separated to the appropriate URL parameter. In your example, the pv0 URL parameter:

```
/[your-report-id]?pv0=OR,FL
```

Comment: Amazing! And after I worried over some of Salesforces functions returning lists of items in this comma-seperated format (What are you thinking, what if the item already has a comma in it). I've been worried that Salesforce wouldn't be able to replicate some of the functionality we got people dependent on. You just made my day. Now where is a sock puppet account so I can vote you up more the once.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can just separate all values by commas in report constructor.